# Rails app doesn't see my views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've on a while on rails now and here's the problem I've been having on and on:

When I create a controller through:

**"rails generate controller ControllerName ViewName"**

I get everything working as I want but if for some reason I create the controller through:

**"rails generate controller ControllerName"**

and then just add ViewName.html.erb to the folder inside views that has the same name as my controller things would go wrong.
So the concrete case is me writing:

**rails generate controller Subjects list show**.

Which creates for me:

```
1.controllers>subjects_controller.rb
2.views>subjects>list.html.erb
3.views>subjects>show.html.erb
```

So this whole thing works fine.But as I already said if I need another view; let's say "new" I just add "new.html.erb" next to the other *.html.erb files **and** an action:

**def new**

**end**

to my **subjects_controller.rb** then it won't work.
The two previous views would keep working but any other "*html.erb" created outside the command line wouldn't.

Is there anywhere else where info about views is being stored?.

I'm a Windows 7 user (32 bit).Rails version=3.0.3. WebServer=WEBrick.
Text editor = E-TextEditor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by your routes not being correctly configured. So it would be helpful to see the content of your routes.rb

In your case I think the best way to configure the routes is to use the resources mapping:

```
resources :subjects
```

This will by default create routing for the standard RESTful actions :index, :show, :edit, :update, :new, :create and :destroy.

For more detailed information about the routing, I would recommend [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: I found out that in the file routes.rb the last line "match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'" should be uncommented for the application to properly relate the controllers with their actions

Comment: I would recommend you not to do that. Those kind of catch-all routes is discouraged. Much better to control your routes by specifying them with resources and match.